# C++/Qt : change (the size of) a QImage that is being painted

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, resize, paintevent

I apologize if I give more details than necessary. I have a class `Canvas` that looks like this:

```
class Canvas : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Canvas(int width = 700, int height = 700, QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setDelegate(CanvasDelegate *delegate);
private:
    CanvasDelegate *delegate;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *resizeEvent);
    [...]
};
```

The `Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` function is implemented like this:

```
void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    delegate->redrawBuffer();
    QPainter canvas_painter(this);
    canvas_painter.drawImage(0, 0, *(delegate->getImage()));
}
```

And so the class `CanvasDelegate` looks like this:

```
class CanvasDelegate
{
    friend class Canvas;

public:
    CanvasDelegate(const Canvas *canvas);
    ~CanvasDelegate();

    const QImage * getImage() const;

    void drawPoint(const Complex &z, const QColor &color = "black", int width = 3);
    [...]
    virtual void redrawBuffer(const H2Isometry &mobius = H2Isometry::identity()) = 0;
    virtual void mousePress(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent) = 0;
    [...]


protected:
    const Canvas *canvas;

    int sizeX, sizeY;
    [...]

    QPen *pen;
    QImage *image;
    QPainter *painter;

    void rescale(int sizeX, int sizeY);
};
```

The constructor of CanvasDelegate is as follows:

```
CanvasDelegate::CanvasDelegate(const Canvas *canvas) : canvas(canvas)
{
    pen = new QPen;
    image = new QImage(canvas->width(), canvas->height(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
    painter = new QPainter(image);
    [...]
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best design ever but this is not my question (any comments are welcome, though). My problem is what happens when the window (`Canvas`) is resized. Here is what my code looks like:

```
void Canvas::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *resizeEvent)
{
    QSize newSize = resizeEvent->size();
    delegate->rescale(newSize.width(), newSize.height());
    //update();
}


void CanvasDelegate::rescale(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    *image = QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    painter->eraseRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);

    this->sizeX = sizeX;
    this->sizeY = sizeY;
    [...]
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, it crashes. Apparently there is a segmentation fault when `painter->eraseRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);` is called in `void CanvasDelegate::rescale(int sizeX, int sizeY)`. I don't understand why, I don't see what the problem is.

In a previous version, I had written the following (which now seems to me more complicated than necessary):

```
void CanvasDelegate::rescale(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    QImage * oldImage = image;
    QImage * newImage = new QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);

    QPainter * oldPainter = painter;
    QPainter * newPainter = new QPainter(newImage);
    newPainter->eraseRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
    newPainter->setPen(*pen);

    image = newImage;
    painter = newPainter;

    delete oldImage;
    delete oldPainter;

    this->sizeX = sizeX;
    this->sizeY = sizeY;
    [...]
}
```

But that does not work: I get a Qt error *QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted*. If I remove `delete oldImage;` and `delete oldPainter;`, everything works fine but that is a disgusting memory leak, isn't it.

Does someone understand why what I have written does not work, and what I need to do?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why `painter->eraseRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);` segfaults, but it may be that when the paintdevice of a QPainter is an image, its size shoudn't change, and therefore `*image = QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);` breaks this assumption.

Therefore, I would try, before resizing the image, to delete the QPainter, then resize the image, then allocate a new QPainter. In code:

```
void CanvasDelegate::rescale(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    delete painter;
    *image = QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    painter = new QPainter(image);
    painter->eraseRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
    painter->setPen(*pen);

    this->sizeX = sizeX;
    this->sizeY = sizeY;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: @Seub See my update, I rarely paint directly on images so my answer was actually wrong in this case. :)

Comment: ok I'm reading your edited answer. But isn't what you are suggesting (more or less) what I've written in my "previous version"?

Comment: @Seub see edit. Not exactly, in your case, you call `image = newImage;`, while `oldPainter` is still "painting" (potentially) on `image`, i.e. the error *QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted*. So `delete oldPainter;` must occur before `image = newImage;`.

Comment: @seub Or actually, simply swapping `delete oldImage;` and `delete oldPainter;` should work.